# How to connect RStudio Cloud to Spark?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I am using RStudio Cloud and I want to connect to Spark using `sparklyr` package. I tried a local master and a `yarn` master. The code is as below.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn")
# Error in system2(file.path(spark_home, "bin", "spark-submit"), "--version", : error in running command
```

Neither worked. I don't know how to set up the Spark environments further. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a problem with the version of Spark.

This works fine for me, on a new project on RStudio Cloud:

```
install.packages("sparklyr")
library(sparklyr)
spark_install(version = "3.0.0")
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
```

[image]